# 4 pairs of triplets and a loose one

Tags: time-signatures

I was trying to transcribe by ear a song on the piano, I've reached a moment where it seems to be that there are 4 pairs of triplets and a loose one (so 4x3 + 1 = 13 loose triplets) but I can´t manage to find the appropriate time signature to complete the bar, I want to put them all in a single bar or divide it in two, one with the first 3 pair of triplets (3/4 time?) and the next with the last pair and the loose one.

Maybe I´m completely wrong and they aren´t even triplets (I´m pretty sure I´m mistaken), so here is the song: Tenhi - Kuvajainen

YouTube Link:

The bar at issue starts at minute 2:30, the first bar has 13 loose triplets and the second 11, so, actually the main question is which is the time signature?

Answer (score 5):

This could be written as an alternation of two [additive meters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_signature#Additive_meters): `9 + 4 / 8` and `9 + 2 / 8`, where the 9 quavers are naturally subdivided in 3+3+3, so no need for triplets. You could also write the two additive meters as `3+3+3+2+2 / 8` and `3+3+3+2 / 8`, but this might be an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Just take your two index fingers and beat them on your table (if you happened to have one - I don't ;-)

*-> (edit: talking about the table not the index finger)*

Start with your stronger hand - for me it's the right hand - and try to make only the sound of the right hand ***( R )*** audible. The left hand ***( L )*** only beats the (almost) inaudible - so called - ghost notes. Like the drummer does on the recording!

What you've got here is a pattern of a **13 / 8** bar and a **11 / 8** bar...

The **13 / 8** is divided into ->  **( 3 - 3 - 3 - 2 - 2 )**
The **11 / 8** is divided into ->  **( 3 - 3 - 3 - 2 )**

Now let's have fun!!! Practice only the **13 / 8** part

**( R L L ) ( R L L ) ( R L L ) ( R L ) ( R L )**

Later go for the **11 / 8** part by dropping the last 2 eights of the **13 / 8** part

**( R L L ) ( R L L ) ( R L L ) ( R L )**

When you got them - combine the whole pattern...

**( R L L ) ( R L L ) ( R L L ) ( R L ) ( R L )

( R L L ) ( R L L ) ( R L L ) ( R L )**

It's almost like the good old 'Take Five' by Dave Brubeck where you have a **5 / 4** measure that is split into **3 + 2** quarter notes. The sax-melody actually does go for the **5 / 4** beat ( in eights ) but for the accompanying piano it is easier to see it as a **10 / 8** pattern. So the first 3 quarter notes are rather 6 eights - but instead of dividing them into **( 2 - 2 - 2 )** eights ( like the Saxophone does ) they are split into **( 3 - 3 )** eights. The last two quarter notes ( 4 eights ) are **( 2 - 2 )** . That finally brings you to 10 eights **( 3 - 3 - 2 - 2 )** instead of the 5 quarter **( 3 + 2 )**. Even the bass player plays a pattern of two dotted quarters ( one of them is 3 eights ) an two plain quarters ( 2 eights ) which is again **( 3 - 3 - 2 - 2 )** .

Now tap them on your table like in the example above

**( R L L ) ( R L L ) ( R L ) ( R L )**

You see - you almost got the same pattern - only one **( R L L )** in the middle is missing. Of course your song is even a bit more sophisticated because the **10 / 8** of 'Take Five' have a basic beat of 5 quarter notes but neither the  **13 / 8**  nor the **11 / 8** bar in your song can be devided by two to get a straight quarter feel that hammers the beat home like in 'Take Five' ...

Although a little bit Off-Topic I hope that helped you to understand the basic structure of the beat of your song better!

Happy Table-Drumming!!!